# Which users should I connect as when backing up multiple hosts to a shared drive?

Tags: backup, time-machine, user-account, smb, network-user

Alice and Bob both have MacBooks. There's an always-on mac mini with a 5TB external drive they want to use for Time Machine backups. Bob signs in to the Mac Mini and plugs in the 5TB drive, and creates subfolders for him and Alice, shares them, marks them as "Time Machine backup" folders, and is able to point his MacBook's Time Machine at it no problem.

Bob uses the Finder on the Mac Mini to give Alice read and write permissions to her backup folder, but her MacBook balks at doing the Time Machine backup with the error "The backup disk image could not be created." Bob sees he can get Alice's Time Machine backup to work if he signs in to the Mac Mini as himself.

Is that the only/optimal way to set that up? Everybody has to connect to the backup host as the same user? Or is there a way for Alice to connect as herself and own her own backup files?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on Apple’s Support site to create the TM destination (network backup)?  See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202784

Comment: I did! And that's how I got as far as that error message mentioned above. You'll notice that there's no mention of users or permissions in that document, except for "on *your* other Mac computers"  which might be implying they have to be the same user?

Comment: What versions of macOS do you have on each machine?  The instructions differ depending on Ventura and earlier

Comment: @Allan this is all macos ventura